# Load data local infile Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c#, mysql, ubuntu

I configured a MySQL server (8.0.23) on a virtual machine (Ubuntu 20.04), this VM is installed on a Windows server on which I installed and configured IIS.

I then developed a C# WebService (installed on the Windows server) to load mass data to the MySQL server installed on the vm. However, I couldn’t make the Load Data Local Infile work, but I did configure it well in the MySQL configuration file as well as in php.ini
I did activate the line mysqli.allow_local_infile in the php.ini and the same for the local_infile in MySQL.

According to my research it would not be possible to use the Load Data Local Infile with a configuration like mine, the MySQL server should have been on the Windows server (The client is king unfortunately :/)

There is my MySQL connectionString :

```
"server=xx.xx.xx.xx;database=" + idWin + ";username=MyUser;password=MyPass;AllowLoadLocalInfile=true;SSL Mode=none"
```

There is my code in C# :

```
        try
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= nbCsv + 1; i++)
            {
                string query = @"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + (tempFileCsv + "_" + (i + dt.Rows.Count) + ".csv") + "' INTO TABLE " + tableName + " FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'µ' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ";
                MySqlCommand commandCreate;
                commandCreate = new MySqlCommand(query, sqlCo);
                commandCreate.CommandTimeout = 1000;
                commandCreate.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorDataInfile = e.Message;
            Logs.AddLog("Erreur Fonction BulkLoadData (LOAD DATA) : " + e.ToString(), 3, "WebServiceGestalia");
        }
```

There is the error when i execute this MySQL command (With teh WebService) :

```
Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.
```

Would it still have a possibility to run the Load Data Local Infile ?

Comment: LOAD DATA does not produce resultset.

Comment: php setting don't affect c#- See [this](https://mysqlconnector.net/troubleshooting/load-data-local-infile/) maybe.